# How to know the numbers of pin code remained on a smart card

Tags: c#, rsa

I'm sing a smart card and a token and I have a code that checks the PIN Code for them, but I want to catch the number of PIN that remains until blocked if the password was incorrect.

this is my code:

```
public static bool IsValidPasswordForCertificate(X509Certificate2 certificate, string password)
{
   CspParameters csp = new CspParameters();

   try
   {
      RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaEncryptor = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
      csp.KeyContainerName = rsaEncryptor.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName;
      csp.ProviderName = rsaEncryptor.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName;
      csp.ProviderType = rsaEncryptor.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType;
   }

   catch (Exception)
   {
      throw;
   }

   //Import the password to the csp details
   try
   {
      SecureString secure = new SecureString();
      foreach (char c in password)
         secure.AppendChar(c);
      csp.KeyPassword = secure;

   }

   catch (Exception)
   {
      throw;
   }

   //Try to import the csp and password details to the provider
   try
   {
      RSACryptoServiceProvider prov = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);
   }

   catch (CryptographicException ex)
   {
      if (ex.Message.Contains("wrong PIN"))
         return false;
   }

   catch (Exception)
   {
      throw;
   }

   return true;
}
```

If the pin is incorrect, the CryptographicException will be thrown, and in that or after this, to know the numbers of retries for PIN that's left until the smart card/token will block.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `catch(Exception){throw;}` blocks? Debugging?

Comment: just to catch any other exception for debug